# BMI formula c# does not

Tags: c#, readline

Please help me! BMI is not calculated correctly! What is the mistake here.

```
 using System;  
 using System.Collections.Generic; 
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Text; 
 using System.Threading.Tasks;


 namespace BMICHECKERARTEHOSER {
     class Program
     {
         static void Main(string[] args)
         {
             Console.WriteLine("Hello, I'm a robot for calculating body mass index!");
             Console.WriteLine("Enter your weight");
             double m = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
             Console.WriteLine(m);
             Console.WriteLine("Enter your height");
             double h = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
             Console.WriteLine(h);
             Console.WriteLine("Your bmi is:");
             double i = Convert.ToDouble(m / (h * h));
             Console.WriteLine(i);

         }
     } }
```

Comment: What numbers did you enter (weight in kilogram, height in meters)? What answer did you get, what did you expect?

Comment: There are couple existing implementations on SO - https://www.bing.com/search?q=C%23%20compute%20bmi%20site%3Astackoverflow.com and most likely plenty on https://CodeReview.stackexchange.com. You can just copy-paste code you like... If you want your version of the question answered please review [MCVE] guidance and [edit] post accordingly. In particular provide exact formula you trying to implement and replace all reading with inline values, make sure to show expected/actual results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are expect weight is kg and height is cm then

Add to last row

```
Console.ReadKey();
```

and

```
double i = Convert.ToDouble(m / (h * h));
```

change:

```
double i = Convert.ToDouble(m / (h * h)) * 10000; // convert to kg/m^2
```

Comment: `double i = m / (h * h) * 10000;` , no need in `Convert.ToDouble`